# How to read two successive files in a folder

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a folder of images and I d like to proceed on them the treatment of (Motion History Image) MHI.
So I didn't know how to take 2 images successively in **FOR LOOP** to work on them.

Any help pls, Thank you!

Comment: Can you share some code? Eg. showing how you would go about iterating through single files, then it's straightforward to show you how to reference two at a time.

Comment: As for the Python version: Are you going to work with Python 2 or 3? Or are you attempting to write 2/3 compatible code? The latter is a noble plan, but I don't recommend it unless absolutely necessary, since it forces you to do a number of ugly hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code will open the first 2 files, then the second pair of new files, and so on so forth

```
files = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']

counter = 0
while counter < len(files):
    file1 = open(files[counter], 'r')
    file2 = open(files[counter + 1], 'r')
    counter += 2
```

The reason a for loop would not work, is that 2.jpg is part of the first set of files, in a for loop without specifying the step, 2.jpg is the first file of the second set, which is incorrect.

so to do this in a for loop, you need something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(files), 2):
    file1 = open(files[i], 'r')
    file2 = open(files[i + 1], 'r')
```

this ofcourse assumes that the list files is sorted correctly, as numeric-strings can be sorted differently, example:

```
files = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg']
files = sorted(files)
```

will produce:

```
['1.jpg', '10.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg']
```

which you can see, the `10.jpg` follows `1.jpg`
An example of how to do this 'nicely' here:

```
import re

def sorted_nicely(l, reverse=False): 
    """ Sort the given iterable in the way that humans expect.""" 
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text 
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)] 
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key, reverse=reverse)
```

*(would love to give credit here, as I probably 'borrowed' this code from the internet somewhere, but cannot remember where)*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work in `2 by 2` manner use:

```
files = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg']
for img1, img2 in zip(files[::2], files[1::2]):
    #do something
```

and if you want to combine in manner `1-2`, `2-3`...:

```
for img1, img2 in zip(files, files[1:]):
    #do something
```